# How to get the least significant 3 bits of a char in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

The following text is what I'm stuck with on a piece of documentation.

> The least significant 3 bits of the first `char` of the array indicates whether
>   it is `A` or `B`. If the 3 bits are `0x2`, then the array is in a `A`
>   format. If the 3 bits are `0x3`, then the array is in a `B` format.

This is the first time in my life I have ever touched on with this *least significant bits* thingy. After searching on StackOverflow, this is what I did:

```
int lsb = first & 3;
if (lsb == 0x02)
{
    // A
}
else if (lsb == 0x03)
{
    // B
}
```

Is this correct? I want to ensure this is the right way (and avoid blowing my foot off later) before I move on.

Comment: Yup, that's correct if you want the TWO least significant bits. You are after the three least significant bits.

Comment: As 3 is 0011 you'd only get the last two bytes, you would have to use 7 (0111) to get the last 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The least significant 3 bits of `x` are taken using `x&7` unlike the `first & 3` you use. In fact `first & 3` will take the least significant 2 bits of `first`.

You should convert the numbers to binary to understand why this is so: 3 in binary is `11`, while 7 is `111`.

Comment: @datenwolf Not really. You can also do it with shifts.

Comment: @PaulManta: What I man it that "can" sounds like you could (errornously) use some other number used as mask as well. I'm aware you can do it with shifts as well, see my answer.

Comment: You can write `(1 << n) - 1` to get an n-bit mask.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, 3 least significant bits should be yourchar&0x07 unstead.

7 because 7 is 1+2+4 or binary 111, corresponding to the 3 LSB.

EDIT: grilled, should be deleted. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The variable you need will have every bit zero and three LSBs 1, which is `0111` in short.

`0111` is `0x7`, use `variable & 0x7` to mask your variable.

Google bit masking for more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
d3 = b11 = b01 | b10
```

So no, right now you're comparing only the 2 LSBs. `b111` would be `d7`

If you want to write down the number of bits to take, You'd have to write it as

```
unsigned int ls3b = ~(UINT_MAX << 3);
```

what this does is, it takes the all 1 bit array, shifts it by 3 bits to the left (leaving the 3 LSBs 0) and then inverts it.